# Prove that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{D}$ that $\left|\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{1-\overline{f(b)}f(a)}\right|\le\left |\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{b}a}\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a analytic with $|f(z)|<1$ .Prove that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{D}$ that $$\left|\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{1-\overline{f(b)}f(a)}\right|\le\left |\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{b}a}\right|.$$

***What I tried***

I am trying to prove by Schwarz lemma for the function $g(z)=\phi_{f(a)}(f(\phi_{-a}(z)))$ where $\phi_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$, but I didn't get the result. Can any one help? Thank you.

Comment: Look up Schwarz Pick Lemma in Wikipedia, there is a proof.

Comment: i dont why down vote  for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. We have that $g:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ and $g(0)=0$, therefore by [Schwarz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma), for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$,
$$|g(z)|=|\phi_{f(a)}(f(\phi_{-a}(z)))|\leq |z|.$$
Now note that $\phi_{a}:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ is a bijection and $\phi_{-a}^{-1}=\phi_{a}$. Then let $z=\phi_{-a}^{-1}(b)=\phi_{a}(b)$.

Comment: thank you i will try according to your hint: @Robert Z

Comment: i am struggling still   this problem and you are updated ..thank you so much...@Robert Z

Comment: i am getting some problems can you please explain two more line..@Robert Z

Comment: Tell me your doubts.

Comment: we need to prove first $g(0)=0$ and $|g(z)|\le |z|$...and then what next is it directly we can say $|\phi_{f(a)(f(b)|}| \le| \phi _b a|$  and i have problem to prove $|g(z)|\le |z|$.

Comment: $g(0)=\phi_{f(a)}(f(\phi_{-a}(0)))=\phi_{f(a)}(f(a))=...$. Then compare
$|\phi_{f(a)}(f(b))| \le |\phi _b a|$ with the desired inequality.

Comment: yes i proved $g(0)=0$ and $|g(z)|<1$ so $|g(z)| \le |z|$ right?

Comment: Yes, thanks to by Schwarz Lemma.